# What does following statement does in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am new to JS with react+redux framework and I have a code that as follows in reducer code.

```
export const operationState = (state = someState, action = {}) => {
    //some case handler 
}
```

Please help me in understanding what will this translates to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exports a function named `operationState` with the parameters state and action, that both default to `someState` and `{}` if nothing is passed in when you call `operationState()`

Comment: Actually it exports a constant with a reference to a function, but why the do that instead of simply writing _export function_ is beyond me